# TypeORM M2O O2M Relationship Foreign Key Is Null when using cascade to insert

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I am currently trying to create a `Many To One` and `One to Many` Relationship using TypeORM without Typescript.

I have the following entities setup:

**./entity/proposal**

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "Proposal",
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "int",
            generated: true
        },
        name: {
            type: "varchar",
            length: 60
        },
        description: {
            type: "varchar",
            default: "",
            length: 150
        },
        createdAt: {
            createDate: true
        },
        updatedAt: {
            updateDate: true
        }
    },
    relations: {
        sections: {
            target: "Section",
            type: "one-to-many",
            treeParent: true,
            cascade: true,
            inverseSide: 'Proposal'
        }
    }
}
```

**./entity/section**

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "Section",
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "int",
            generated: true
        },
        name: {
            type: "varchar",
            length: 60,
            default: "New Section"
        },
        order: {
            type: "int"
        }
    },
    relations: {
      proposal: {
          target: "Proposal",
          type: "many-to-one",
          joinColumn: true,
          nullable: false
      }
  }
}
```

From here I have created two functions, one for inserting a proposal and another function which I'm using to create mock data which uses the cascade feature to insert rows (as per this example: https://github.com/typeorm/javascript-example)

**./controller/createProposal.js**

```js
const getRepository = require('typeorm').getRepository

const createProposal = async proposal => {

    let proposalRepository = getRepository("Proposal");
    let result = await proposalRepository.save(proposal)
            .then( savedProposal  => {
                return savedProposal
            })
            .catch( err => {
                return {
                    message: "There was an issue saving the proposal",
                    err: err
                }
            });

    return result

}

module.exports = createProposal
```

**./controller/mockData.js**

```js
const createProposal = require('../proposal/createProposal')

const insertMockData = async () => {

  let section1 = {
    name: "Letter",
    order: 1
  }

  let section2 = {
    name: "Cloud",
    order: 2
  }

  let proposal = {
    name: "Cloud Proposal",
    description: "Cloud Proposal",
    sections: [
      section1, section2
    ] 
  }

  let result = await createProposal(proposal)

}

module.exports = insertMockData
```

Using the `insertMockData()` function with `nullable: true` results in the following:

```
=== Proposal Table ===
id  name                 description
1   "Cloud Proposal"     "Cloud Proposal"
```

```
=== Section Table ===
id  name        order     proposalid
1   "Letter"    1         null
2   "Cloud"     2         null
```

I need to have the `proposalid` present inside the section table so I can eager find it with `proposalRepository.findOneOrFail({ id , relations: ['sections'] })`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you can also share `createProposal` function it's will be great. Currently, we don't see how actual create the `proposal` object.

Comment: @DavidWeinberg Hi David, please see the second from the bottom code block :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `eager: true` to `Section->proposal`

```
relations: {
    proposal: {
        target: "Proposal",
        type: "many-to-one",
        joinColumn: true,
        nullable: false,
        eager: true // This line
    }
}
```

Comment: what the `eager: true` means?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can be useful to someone.
I recently experienced the same issues on a `one-to-many` and `many-to-one` relationship using TypeORM with NodeJS (version `0.2.18`).

This are the working entities with working relationship:

```js
const { EntitySchema } = require('typeorm')

const FirstEntity = require('../model/FirstEntity')

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'FirstEntity',
  target: FirstEntity,
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'bigint',
      generated: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'timestamp with time zone',
      default: () => 'NOW()',
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'timestamp with time zone',
      default: () => 'NOW()',
    },
    ...........
  },
  relations: {
    secondentities: {
      target: 'SecondEntity',
      type: 'one-to-many',
      cascade: true,
      inverseSide: 'firstEntity',
      eager: true,
      nullable: false,
    },
  },
})
```

```js
const { EntitySchema } = require('typeorm')

const SecondEntity = require('../model/SecondEntity')

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'SecondEntity',
  target: SecondEntity,
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'bigint',
      generated: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'timestamp with time zone',
      default: () => 'NOW()',
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'timestamp with time zone',
      default: () => 'NOW()',
    },
    ...........
  },
  relations: {
    firstEntity: {
      target: 'FirstEntity',
      type: 'many-to-one',
      inverseSide: 'secondentities',
      nullable: false,
    },
  },
})
```

My very first issue was that `.save()` of the `firstEntity` was not saving at all the nested `secondentities`. It was solved by the `cascade` property.

My second issue, after adding the `cascade`, was that the saved `firstEntity` `id` was missing in the `secondentities` saved into the DB. It was solved by adding the `inverseSide` property.

Please note that the `nullable` properties were not working at all, so after the `.save()` I had to manually `.findOneOrFail` the saved `firstEntity` and check for the `secondentities` existence.